# Swagger.js Cannot read property 'get' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I am trying to create a Swagger spec and application for my express api. My app.js file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var tenants = require('./routes/tenants');

var models = require('./models.js');
var resources = require('./resources.js')

var app = express();
var swagger = require('swagger-node-express').createNew(app);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

swagger.addModels(models);
swagger.addGet(resources.getTenantById);//This is where I am getting the error

swagger.setApiInfo({
  title: "Swagger Sample App",
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server. You can find out more about Swagger at <a href=\"http://swagger.wordnik.com\">http://swagger.wordnik.com</a> or on irc.freenode.net, #swagger.  For this sample, you can use the api key \"special-key\" to test the authorization filters",
  termsOfServiceUrl: "http://helloreverb.com/terms/",
  contact: "apiteam@wordnik.com",
  license: "Apache 2.0",
  licenseUrl: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
});

swagger.configureSwaggerPaths("", "api-docs", "")
swagger.configure("http://localhost:8002", "1.2.0");

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/tenants',tenants);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


app.listen(8002);
```

My resources.js file is :

```
var sw = require('./node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node');
var swe = sw.swagger.errors;
var params = sw.paramTypes;
var url = require('url');

exports.getTenantById = {
    'spec' : {
        description : "Operations on Tenants",
        path : "tenants/{tenantId}",
        method : "GET",
        nickname : "getTenantById",
        summary : "Find Tenant by Id",
        notes : "Returns a tenant by Id",
        type : "Tenant",
        produces : ["application/json"],
        parameters : [params.path("tenantId","ID of the Tenant","string")],
        responseMessages : [swe.invalid('tenantId')]
    },
    'action' : function(req,res){
        if(!req.params.tenantId){
            console.log("Tenants Id not provided");
            return res;
        }

        var tenant = {
            "id" : res.params.tenantId
        }

        res.send(JSON.stringify(tenant));
    }
};
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.10.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.11.1",
    "jade": "~1.9.1",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "swagger-node-express": "~2.0"  
  }
}
```

The link to swagger-node-express : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node-express

And the error I am getting after running node app.js command:

```
Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node/swagger.js:446
    app[currentMethod](fullPath, function (req, res, next) {
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null
    at Swagger.addMethod (/Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node/swagger.js:446:8)
    at /Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node/swagger.js:495:10
    at Function.forOwn (/Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:1301:15)
    at Swagger.addHandlers (/Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node/swagger.js:493:5)
    at Swagger.addGet.Swagger.addGET (/Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/node_modules/swagger-node-express/Common/node/swagger.js:520:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deepaksharma/Documents/PROGRAMMING/sample-express-app/myapp/app.js:31:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I cannot understand why I am getting a null error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It is a silly mistake. I forgot to add models.model in line 30 of app.js. I am importing models.js into the variable models but not using the exported variable models.model in addModels() on line 30 of app.js.

This question can be closed because it does not add anything useful to the community.

Comment: Don't assume this doesn't add anything to the community. I bet there are hundreds of people who made the exact same mistake as you did